# Ajax code to display comment/information box if web page doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below code,

```
<script>
    function AjaxLoadFWs() {
        var sPath = window.location.pathname;
        var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        $('#overviewfw').load("http://test.com/test.asp");
        change_overview();
        change_overview_detail();
    }
</script>
```

Now I need to display a message if **http://test.com/test.asp** doesn't load within 10 seconds.

What code needs to be added please?

Comment: Please write what have you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load()` call is a convenient shorthand for `.ajax()`. Since you want a `timeout` of 10 seconds I would suggest to use `ajax` instead because it offers more options:

```
$.ajax('http://test.com/test.asp', {
   timeout: 10000, // 10 seconds
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      //here you have to process the data you get
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //here you can handle the timeout.
   }
});
```